# MySQL check ENUM column in another table throughout constraint

Tags: mysql, reference, constraints

I have two tables:

```
--
--
--
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
      PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
      `staff_id`    SMALLINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name`        VARCHAR(50)          NOT NULL,
      `staff_type`  ENUM('expert',        # Perito
                         'injured'        # Danneggiato
                    ) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `x8k1y_staff`
  (`staff_id`, `name`, `staff_type`)
VALUES
  (1, 'Name surname', 'expert'),
  (2, 'John Doe', 'injured');

--
--
--
CREATE TABLE `risk_location` (
    PRIMARY KEY (`risk_loc_id`),
    `risk_loc_id` INT         UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `injured`     SMALLINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT `fk_injured`
      FOREIGN KEY (`injured`)
      REFERENCES `staff` (`staff_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But I want to raise an MySQL Error if a user tries to insert a `staff_id` that doesn't have a value of "injured" in `staff_type`.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO risk_location (`injured`)
VALUES (1); # <--- Here I want an error, because the `staff_type` of id 1 is `expert`

INSERT INTO risk_location (`injured`)
VALUES (2); # <--- This is ok
```

Thank you

Comment: you have to use a trigger for that

Comment: What is a MySQL Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a constarint

but you can use a trigger

eventually you need a DELIMITER before and after, depending how you add a trigger

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `staff` (
>       PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
>       `staff_id`    SMALLINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       `name`        VARCHAR(50)          NOT NULL,
>       `staff_type`  ENUM('expert',        # Perito
>                          'injured'        # Danneggiato
>                     ) NOT NULL
> )ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `staff`
>   (`staff_id`, `name`, `staff_type`)
> VALUES
>   (1, 'Name surname', 'expert'),
>   (2, 'John Doe', 'injured');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `risk_location` (
>     PRIMARY KEY (`risk_loc_id`),
>     `risk_loc_id` INT         UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `injured`     SMALLINT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>
>     CONSTRAINT `fk_injured`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`injured`)
>       REFERENCES `staff` (`staff_id`)
>       ON DELETE CASCADE
> )ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_risk_location_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON risk_location FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE _staff_type varchar(10);
>     
>     SELECT staff_type 
>     INTO _staff_type
>     FROM staff
>     WHERE staff_id = NEW.injured;
>     
>     IF _staff_type =  'expert' THEN
>         signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'user is expert'; 
>
>     END IF; 
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO risk_location (`injured`)
> VALUES (1); # <--- Here I want an error, because the `staff_type` of id 1 is `expert`
> ```

> ```
> user is expert
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO risk_location (`injured`)
> VALUES (2); # <--- This is ok
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e633ff6db8647c97fe67c259f522f70c)*